# DropDown Selected value showing 0 on SelectedIndexChange in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a dropdownlist, I am binding them using JQuery, AJAX webservice,  But when i am trying to retrieve selected value of that DropDownList on SelectedIndexChange. i am getting 0 (zero)

**Before Binding DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbillNumber" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlbillNumber_SelectedIndexChange" 
                                    AutoPostBack="true" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

**JSON & AJAX Code:**

```
function GetBillNumbers() {
            //debugger;
            var ClientName = $("#<%=HiddenFieldCompanyId.ClientID %>").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%=mstr_WebsitePath%>webservice/ClientSearch.asmx/GetClientBillNumber",
                data: "{ 'ClientName' : '" + ClientName + "' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var ddlbillNumber = $("[id*=ddlbillNumber]");
                    ddlbillNumber.empty().append('<option value="0">--select--</option>');
                    $.each(r.d, function () {
                        ddlbillNumber.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

**After Binding DropDownList in Browser Code:**

```
<select name="ddlbillNumber" id="ctl00_body_ddlbillNumber">
<option value="0">--select--</option>
  <option value="VMPL/Delhi/001/15-16">VMPL/Delhi/001/15-16</option>
</select>
```

Then I am selecting second option means VMPL/Delhi/001/15-16 but getting 0
Code:

```
Protected Sub ddlbillNumber_SelectedIndexChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim Bill As String = ddlbillNumber.SelectedItem.Value // Here I am getting zero
            If Bill <> "" Then
                Dim Vasundhara As String = Bill.Substring(0, 2)
                If Vasundhara = "VI" Then
                    GetInfotechBill(Bill, 1)
                ElseIf Vasundhara = "VM" Then
                    GetInfotechBill(Bill, 0)
                End If
                PanelPrintDuplicatBill.Visible = True
            End If
End Sub
```

**My Screenshot is attached :**
[image]

Comment: How do you data bind the drop down list?

Comment: use `SelectedValue` instead.

Comment: Ensure you are not binding dropdownlist in postback as it will remove any selection you made

Comment: I have used `SelectValue` as well as `SelectedItem.Text`. But all time i am getting 0 . I am binding my `DropDownList` using `AJAX JSON`

Comment: "using AJAX JSON" is not a complete description. Can you please show us how you do it? As Adil mentioned, the problem might be in the way you implemented data binding

Comment: Hello #Andrei. I have added my full code please see them